# Button doesn't perform action

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qt5.2

I'm trying to perform action, when user clicks on button. 
My code is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtUiTools/QUiLoader>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    createActions();
}

void MainWindow::test()
{
    //QMessageBox::information(this, "Welcome", "Select first image.");
    //QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, QT_TR_NOOP("Open Image"), "D:\\", QT_TR_NOOP("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
    resize(100,500);
}

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    QWidget *centralWidget = this->centralWidget();
    QPushButton *buttonBack = centralWidget->findChild<QPushButton *>("pushButton");
    QObject::connect(buttonBack,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(test()));

    QAction *open = this->findChild<QAction *>("actionOpen");
    //QMessageBox::information(this, "Welcome", open->text());

    connect(open, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(test()));
}
```

Function `void MainWindow::test()` is defined as SLOT in header file and I'm sure, that `QPushButton *buttonBack` isn't null. What I'm doing wrong?

In my code I tried also to perform action through `QAction`, but in this case, function is performed, when I close window.

Comment: Did you have a look in your debug output? It complains when it cannot connect a SIGNAL to a SLOT. Another solution would be to use the new SIGNAL/SLOT syntax in Qt5 http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html

Comment: Have you added the Q_OBJECT macro to your class declaration? Otherwise the Ot Meta Object Compiler (moc) will not run on that class and signals and slots will not work.

Comment: @ChrisInked
No complains in output and program exited with code 0. But I'll check the link. Thanks.

Comment: @maddin45
Yes, I have Q_OBJECT macro in my header file. But thanks.

Comment: And it seems odd that your createActions method is called in the destructor (:

Comment: @ChrisInked
Ou... That's wrong :/ Stupid mistake, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're setting all your actions in the destructor.

Think about what this is doing:

1. UI starts up all happy with the `setupUi()` call from the constructor
2. Throughout the lifetime of the UI, there are no buttons assigned to any slots. This means the signal from your button will never get to the slot `test()`.
3. Upon exit of the UI, the button is connected to the slot.

If you want this to happen, that's cool, but if you want the button to connect to the slot while the UI is running, move your `createActions()` function into the constructor.

Good luck!